# General formula for number of elements of a given order in finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Is there a general formula to find the number of elements of a given order ?

For example, how many elements of order 5 are in a group with 15 elements? And if we try to find the number of elements of order 6 in S4 using  Euler's totient function where S4 has 0 elements of order 6 can any one clarify when to use Euler's function and when not?
Thank you

Comment: For $G=S_n$ see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965699/is-there-a-general-formula-for-the-number-of-elements-of-order-k-in-s-n?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a formula, because the number of elements of order $m$ of two groups $G$ and $H$ may be distinct even if $\#G=\#H$. For instance $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has $1$ element of order $4$, whereas $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ has none.

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos what about Cn groups and Z/nZ can we always use Euler Function

Comment: @Sara Yes, of course.